# Laravel DB count gives different value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm getting 2 different values for users table. The DB table is giving more users than using the User.

```
User::count() //10142
DB::table('users')->count() //10418
```

Comment: are you using soft deletes?

Comment: are you using something like soft deletes?

Comment: There may be a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes) registered for Users, which applies a where criteria to the model query in the background.

Comment: ahhh yes. My mistake. I forgot about soft delete. Should have added  ->whereNull('deleted_at')